# How to solve this error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptions.isStrict()

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I am using the following dependencies in my gradle.build file

```
ext{
    serenity_core_version = "2.5.8"
    serenity_cucumber_version = "6.11.0"
    serenity_cucumber5_version = "2.2.6"
}
dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:$serenity_core_version"
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:$serenity_core_version"
    compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:$serenity_cucumber_version"
    compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:$serenity_cucumber_version"
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:$serenity_core_version"
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-webdriver:$serenity_core_version"
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-emailer:2.1.0"
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-rest:$serenity_core_version"
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber5:$serenity_cucumber5_version"
    compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:$serenity_core_version"
    }
```

my runner is configured as follows

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/features/MiPrimerTest",
    glue = "co.com.testrest.automation.rest",
    stepNotifications = true,
    tags = "@primeraprueba")
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
public class PrimeraPrueba {}
```

[image]

when I execute the following exception comes up

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

From 2.3.x, serenity core only support cucumber 6.x and you don't need to explicit the version of cucumber, so you can remove

```
compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:$serenity_cucumber_version"
compile "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:$serenity_cucumber_version"
compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber5:$serenity_cucumber5_version"
```

but need to add `serenity-cucumber6`

```
compile "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber6:$serenity_core_version"
```

you can see the sample project here https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-cucumber-starter/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have multiple Cucumber dependencies in your Gradle. (*I recommend you to not repeat libraries which can help you to avoid later possible conflicts.*).

And since you are working with Serenity, the only one you should have is "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber6" (*so please remove all the extra dependencies*) in the same version as your "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core"

I use Serenity with Cucumber in this way and it works without problem:

```
ext {
serenityVer = '2.6.0'
junitVer = '4.13.2'
assertJ = '3.20.2'}

dependencies {
implementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityVer}",
        "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:${serenityVer}",
        "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-report-resources:${serenityVer}",
        "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay-rest:${serenityVer}",
        "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-ensure:${serenityVer}",
        "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber6:${serenityVer}",
        "junit:junit:${junitVer}",
        "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertJVer}"}
```